# Падает git при попытке push из IDEA

Tags: git, intellij-idea, git-push

Дано:

1. Intellij IDEA 2019.2.2;
2. Git 2.23.0;
3. Локальный git-сервер на базе gitea версии 1.9.3.

Проблема:
Git падает при попытке осуществления push из idea. Если делать push из консоли (или из терминала IDEA) то все проходит без ошибок.
Сервер gitea прописан в настройках корректно, и при нажатии кнопки "Тест" тест проходит успешно:

[image]

Git remotes:

[image]

Ошибка при попытке push:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

> Сигнатура проблемы:
>   Имя события проблемы: APPCRASH
>   Имя приложения:   git-remote-http.exe
>   Версия приложения:    2.16.1.2
>   Отметка времени приложения:   5a7491f4
>   Имя модуля с ошибкой: git-remote-http.exe 
>   Версия модуля с ошибкой:  2.16.1.2
>   Отметка времени модуля с ошибкой: 5a7491f4
>   Код исключения:   c0000005 
>   Смещение исключения:  00000000000056cd
>   Версия ОС:    6.1.7601.2.1.0.256.48 
>   Код языка:    1049
>   Дополнительные сведения 1:    2c94
>   Дополнительные сведения 2:    2c949939b385f22258e640a7148bc04f 
>   Дополнительные сведения 3:    0239 
>   Дополнительные сведения 4:    023918f574113793afbf28198f23099c

Команда которую выполняет git при попытке push из IDEA:

```
git -c credential.helper= -c core.quotepath=false -c log.showSignature=false push --progress --porcelain origin refs/heads/master:master --tags
```

Если эту команду выполнить вручную то все работает.

Comment: Тест сообщения об ошибке лучше приводить/дублировать тестом. Это позволит другим посетителям ресурса найти данный вопрос

Comment: Нет ли в настройках IDEA Settings > Version Control > Git > Path to Git executable ссылки на старую версию git?

Comment: Да именно так и было. Когда обновил версию git, не обратил внимание, что новая версия встала по другому пути. Ответьте пожалуйста отдельным постом, я отмечу этот пост как решение проблемы.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ошибка была в том что путь (к git) указанный в переменной path и путь расположения git в настройках IDEA отличался. Как только указал одинаковый путь к расположению git ошибка ушла. Спасибо [Spatz](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/195483/spatz) за подсказку.